# the web camera in primefaces is not increse either the width or the heigh of the camera in primefaces code blow

Tags: jsf, primefaces

in primefaces web camera is not increase the size of the photo or the camera in JSF code how to solve this proble

```
        <p:photoCam widgetVar="pc" listener="#{photoCamView.oncapture}" update="photo" />
        <p:commandButton type="button" value="Capture" onclick="PF('pc').capture()"/>
        <p:outputPanel id="photo">
            <p:graphicImage name="#{photoCamView.filename}" rendered="#{not empty photoCamView.filename}"/>
        </p:outputPanel>

        </h:form>            
            <br />
```

and the Java code is

```
public void oncapture(CaptureEvent captureEvent) {
    filename = getRandomImageName();
    byte[] data = captureEvent.getData();

    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    System.out.println("HH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!11");
    File newFileName = new File("C:\\Users\\adane\\Desktop\\PhotoCam\\Image"+filename + ".jpeg");

    FileImageOutputStream imageOutput;
    try {
        imageOutput = new FileImageOutputStream(newFileName);
        imageOutput.write(data, 0, data.length);
        imageOutput.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        throw new FacesException("Error in writing captured image.", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome! I am curious: nothing in your code actually tries to change the size of the camera feed. Are you asking for what code to put into these examples to accomplish this?

Comment: yes you see the code above

Comment: width and height of camera